# Equation name display, not equation labeling/cross-referencing or equation tagging

Tags: math-mode, environments, displaystyle

Is it possible to display an equation name similar to theorem name displays:

```
\begin{theorem}[Convergence of Cauchy Sequences in $\mathbb{R}$]
Every Cauchy sequence of real numbers is also a convergent sequence of real numbers.
\end{theorem}
```

So that the theorem number is followed by "*Convergence of Cauchy Sequences in `$\mathbb{R}$`*". I would like to know if that is possible for equations. One example of what I would like to do is:

```
\begin{equation}[Faraday's Law of Induction]
\nabla\times{\bf E}=-\frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:Faraday}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{Equation}[1][]
  {\par\noindent\refstepcounter{equation}\textbf{\arabic{equation}: #1}\[}
  {\]}

\begin{document}

\begin{Equation}[Faraday's Law of Induction]
\nabla\times{\bf E}=-\frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:Faraday1}
\end{Equation}

\begin{Equation}[Faraday's Law of Induction]
\nabla\times{\bf E}=-\frac{\partial{\bf B}}{\partial t}
\label{eqn:Faraday2}
\end{Equation}

see eqn~\ref{eqn:Faraday1} and eqn~\ref{eqn:Faraday2}
\end{document}
```

[image]